# Can not run image in Bluemix container, cf ic ps shows status building for 3 mins, then shutdown

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have an image that is tested on local docker container. After push it to Bluemix registry, I can not start it. See the attached image please.[image]

There is no data in the Bluemix Dashboard "Monitoring" and "logging" tab. Also nothing displays when I do "cf ic logs {containerId}"

Can you please help me on how to debug this?b

Comment: Does the image works if you run in your local docker? Is it possible for you to update your question and add your Dockerfile as well?

Comment: In addition to the above (particularly copying the container to local and testing there), `cf ic inspect {containerId}` will sometimes show why the container failed to start.

Comment: @NFritze what parameter to look at in the output of cf ic inspect to find the error?

Comment: Look in the "State" block, particularly at State.error (presuming that State.Status is something like "ERROR" or similar.)